# ¡Se requiere servicio de hospedaje especial para una pagina web tipo CRM donde los usuarios pagaran por el servicio?

Tags: hosting

Estoy desarrollando una pagina web tipo CRM donde los usuarios externos podrán almacenar datos de sus clientes. Este acceso tendrá un costo mensual para los usuarios. Se requiere añlgun tipo especial de hospedaje o puede ser en un servicio normal de hospedaje compartido como Hostinger.. entiendo que tienen limitaciones de conexiones simultaneas pero hay algun problema con el acceso de terceros?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esta pregunta esta basada en opiniones.. la mia?? si voy a pagar por un servicio , mejor que tenga cero problemas de conexion al mismo...

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Para ser franco, si preguntas eso, el pretender hacer un CRM te va a sobrepasar. Considera comenzar con una página web simple.

Comment: No existen limitaciones tecnicas. Pero existe el tema de calidad del servicio que debes preocuparte (latencia, uptime, respaldos, etc)